# In Spotfire, how to color value if less than previous value in the same column?

Tags: colors, spotfire

I have a table visualization in Spotfire that I want the cell to color red if less than the previous value in the same column. For example:
500
400
800
100

The 400 would be red and the 100 would be red because they are less than the previous.

I searched through questions but didn't find many results (probably due to too many search terms).

Thank you for your help,

Chris Habrock

Answer (score 0):

For this you're going to need two calculated columns because Spotfire, apparently, doesn't allow OVER expressions in color by rules. 
The first calculated column is defined as:

```
RowID() as [rid]
```

The second one is defined as:

```
First([num]) OVER (Previous([rid])) as [check]
```

With this your color rule can be "less than First([check]).
[image]

I hope this helps.

Comment: I think I figured it out. If I color the row and add a rule that evaluates on less than or equal to and then the value is a custom expression where I use the OVER PreviousNode function.